# Look for a auto indentation plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, indentation, xtend

Today I'm trying the [xtend](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/xtend/) to write a simple program. Looks good, but it doesn't support code formatting!

So I'm looking for an Eclipse plugin that can auto indent the code. No matter xtend or other language that eclipse doesn't support, it can auto indent them.

Is there any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no plugin for Eclipse that allows to format Xtend files without breaking the template expressions. Indentation should work when you write your code in the Xtend editor but there is no such thing as a beautifier available yet. We'll probably have one for the Eclipse Juno release but I can't promise that.